# awk - Find the top url based on error code

Tags: linux, awk, cat

I am creating a sript to pre-analyze access logs from my website. So far I have been using awk to get desired data.

I need to be able to use awk to analyze the top URL, but only for a specific error code. (In this case 404)

Simplified log structure as follows:

```
'Request Method, URI, Error Code'

GET, /foo, 404
GET, /foo, 200
GET, /foo, 404
GET, /foo, 404
GET, /bar, 200
GET, /bar, 404
GET, /foobar, 404
GET, /foobar, 404
```

My desired output would be (Listing top URLS that have 404 error Code):

```
3 /foo
2 /foobar
1 /bar
```

Comment: Try `grep -w 404 $file | uniq -c | sort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk '$3==404{a[$2]++}END{for(url in a){print a[url], url}}' log.txt | sort -rn
```

Comment: This worked! Just changed the last part to | sort -rn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution where the output of the array screening is directly sorted by awk.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ FS = ","; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_desc" }{ if ($3 ~ "404") a[$2]++ }END{ for ( i in a ) print a[i], i }' yourfile
```

Output:

```
3  /foo
2  /foobar
1  /bar
```

Answer (score -2):

awk -F "," '{print $2,$3}' l.txt  | grep -i "404" |awk '{print $1}'

Comment: Not only is this very clumsy, it also doesn't solve the problem described and produce the specified output.  The output *you* generated could more efficiently be produced like so `awk -F "," '/404/{print $2}' l.log`.