# awk - Find the top url based on 4xx error code

Tags: linux, awk, cat

This is a follow up question from the one I posted yesterday that was answered:

[awk - Find the top url based on error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213752/awk-find-the-top-url-based-on-error-code/47228876#47228876)

I used yesterdays answer and modified it from grabbing just 404 error codes, to now grabbing all 4xx.

```
awk '$3 ~ /^4/{a[$2]++}END{for(url in a){print a[url], url}}' samplelog.txt | sort -rn
```

This does work, but now I am wanting a more granular output. Right now it groups all 4xx together, for example a 403 and 404 will be counted as 2, not uniquely. I want to be able to count all 4xx, but then separate them by their unique codes.

Sample Log:

```
GET /foo 404
GET /foo 200
GET /foo 404
GET /foo 404
GET /foo 400
GET /foo 403
GET /foo 403
GET /bar 200
GET /bar 400
GET /foobar 404
GET /foobar 200
GET /foobar 404
GET /foobar 403
```

Result with current script (same as above)

```
awk '$3 ~ /^4/{a[$2]++}END{for(url in a){print a[url], url}}' samplelog.txt | sort -rn    

6 /foo
3 /foobar
1 /bar
```

Desired Result

```
3 /foo 404
2 /foo 403
2 /foobar 404
1 /foo 400
1 /bar 400
1 /foobar 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '$3~/^4/{a[$2 FS $3]++} END{for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file | 
  sort -k1,1nr -k2,2

3 /foo 404
2 /foo 403
2 /foobar 404
1 /bar 400
1 /foo 400
1 /foobar 403
```